# getSubImage() Triggers RasterFormatException

Tags: java, image

This program is supposed to take a screenshot (haystack) and then look for a sub-image (needle) within the screenshot. It then outputs the location of the needle. It uses a for loop to loop through each dimension. It goes from left->right and top->bottom. In line 36 and 37, an RasterFormatException is thrown from within the getSubImage() method.

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws HeadlessException, AWTException,   IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

        BufferedImage haystack = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));

        Point p = findNeedle (ImageIO.read(new File ("needle.png")));

        System.out.println(p.getX() + ", " + p.getY());
    }

    static Point findNeedle(BufferedImage needle) throws HeadlessException, AWTException {
        BufferedImage haystack = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));

        for (int i = 0; i < haystack.getHeight(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < haystack.getWidth(); j++) {


                if (haystack.getSubimage(j, i, haystack.getWidth() - needle.getWidth(),
                        haystack.getHeight() - needle.getHeight()) == needle) {
                    return new Point(j, i);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is the error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.image.RasterFormatException: (x + width) is outside raster
    at sun.awt.image.IntegerInterleavedRaster.createWritableChild(IntegerInterleavedRaster.java:467)
    at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getSubimage(BufferedImage.java:1173)
    at test.Test.findNeedle(Test.java:36)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:20)"
```

Comment: "Is outside raster" don't explain something?

Comment: The stack trace says `test.Test.findSpectators()` but I don't see it being called in your code (nor the method).

Comment: @davidbuzatto I understand now. The centre is still in the haystack whereas the sides aren't.

Comment: Is `==` really the way you want to compare 2 images?

Comment: @JonLin Would variation mess things up greatly?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/3166402

Answer (score 0):

You are always getting the subImage with the width of **haystack.getWidth() - needle.getWidth()** and height of **haystack.getHeight() - needle.getHeight()**.
But you loop through the entire width and height of the haystack image.

Say the haystack is 100x100 pixels and the needle is 10x10 pixels. So the sub image would be 90x90 pixels.

During the for loop, the first 10 times will work, as 10+90 = 100. But the 11th time, you get a problem: 11+90 = 101.
Since 101 is bigger than the haystack image, it tries to create a subImage that is outside the range of the haystack image.

A fix:

```
public class Test
{

public static void main(String[] args) throws HeadlessException, AWTException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException
{

    BufferedImage haystack = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));

    Point p = findNeedle(ImageIO.read(new File("needle.png")), haystack);

    System.out.println(p.getX() + ", " + p.getY());
}

static Point findNeedle(BufferedImage needle, BufferedImage haystack) throws HeadlessException, AWTException
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= haystack.getWidth() - needle.getWidth(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= haystack.getHeight() - needle.getHeight(); j++)
        {
            if (haystack.getSubimage(i, j, needle.getWidth(), needle.getHeight()) == needle)
            {
                return new Point(j, i);
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

The error (Which I didn't spot the first time), was that the subimage had the difference of the two other images as its size, while it should only be the size of the needle.
Please bear in mind that using `needle == subImage` won't work.
while the content of the image might be the same, the two image objects are not equal.

Comment: you would also need to set i and j to the height and width of the needle.

Comment: So that the left and top parts of the needle won't fall off.

Comment: @Marv Take a look at this image: [Link](http://i48.tinypic.com/1erk2b.jpg). There I sketched the search area of the 3 codes (Yours, mine and mine with your suggestion). Green area is the valid searched area, red is where you will get the exception and blue is areas that aren't ever being searched.

Comment: Thank you. I understand now. I was previously under the impression that i and j represent the center of the sub-image. However, even with the changes, the code still outputs the same error.

Comment: @Marv Alright, I should have fixed it now. (At least it works with some dummy images I used). To check if the 2 images are the same, you would need to check if the color of all the pixels are the same for example.